# Laravel 8 - All validation rules are shown if one rule applies

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using `Laravel Framework 8.62.0` and I am having the following validation rules:

```
        $rules=[
            'username' => 'required|min:3|max:30|alpha_dash',
            'email' => "required|email|unique:users,email",
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ];
        $error_messages=[
            'username.required'=>'The username-field is required.',
            'username.min'=>'Your username must be longer than 3 characters.',
            'username.max'=>'Please shorten your username.',
            'username.alpha_dash'=>'Please use letters from A-Z and a-z, dashes (-) or underscores(_).',
            'email.unique'=>'Your email is already used.',
            'email.email'=>'Please add a correct email-address.',
            'email.required'=>'The email-field is required.',
            'password.required'=>'The password-field is required.',
            'password.min'=>'Your password must have at least 6 characters.',
            'password.confirmed'=>'Your entered passwords do not match.',
        ];
        $validator = validator($request->all(), $rules, $error_messages);
```

My form looks like the following:

```
                                                        <form id="Register" class="card-body" tabindex="500" action="{{ url('register') }}" method="POST">
                                <!-- CSRF Token -->
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                                <div class="name">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" value="{!! old('username') !!}">
                                    <label>Username</label>
                                    <li>
                                    {!! $errors->first('username.required', '<ul><span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span></ul>') !!}
                                    {!! $errors->first('username.min', '<ul><span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span></ul>') !!}
                                    {!! $errors->first('username.max', '<ul><span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span></ul>') !!}
                                    {!! $errors->first('username.alpha_dash', '<ul><span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span></ul>') !!}
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mail">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                    <label>Mail</label>
                                    {!!  $errors->first('email.unique', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                    {!!  $errors->first('email.required', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                    {!!  $errors->first('email.email', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="passwd">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    {!! $errors->first('password.min', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                    {!! $errors->first('password.confirmed', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                    {!! $errors->first('password.required', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="passwd">
                                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" value="{{ old('password_confirmation') }}">
                                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                    {!! $errors->first('password.confirmed', '<span style="color: red;" class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="submit">
                                    <!-- <a class="btn ripple  btn-primary btn-block" href="#">Register</a> -->
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn ripple  btn-primary btn-block" value="Register">
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-dark mb-0">Already have an account?<a href="{{ url('login') }}" class="text-primary ml-1">Sign In</a></p>
                            </form>
```

When I enter a username with 3 characters and without a `-` and my password lengths do not match I get all validation errors back:

[image]

However, I would only like to get the errors back that really apply.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the blade file to display every error *that you have created* by name/key, rather than seeing what's inside the error bag.

Laravel automatically presents the errors that apply to your page, and limits the output to only those that apply.  You don't need to catch them individually by name as you have with `$errors->first('email.unique')`... etc.

Take a look at [the docs on how to display validation errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors), it's pretty nifty.  Basically check the error bag and if they are presented, display only those that are in the bag:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

The `$errors` variable is available to you on any view within a route under the web middleware.